# Ajax done appending to last cell in foreach

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am relatively new to jQuery and am trying to achieve the following:

I have a table and for each last cell I want to use the cells value in a ajax request and add the ajax reply in that cell.

```
$('#btn_adt').on("click", function() {

  $('.tg td:nth-child(8)').each(function() {

      $that = $(this);

      function ajax() {
              return $.ajax('/echo/xml/');
                       }

ajax().done(function(result) {
           $that.append('<P>' + result + '</P>');
       }).fail(function() {
           $that.append('<P>Not able to find info!</P>')
        })
    })
});
```

My problem is that all my replies get added to the last cell of the table. Is there something I'm missing? From what I read about the done function is that is should run after ajax has completed.

https://jsfiddle.net/andreitudose/Lwzv0eao/15/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the index and object from the each() function and won't lose your $that reference:

```
$('.tg td:nth-child(8)').each(function(i, o) {
...
$(o).append('<P>' + result + '</P>');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lwzv0eao/18/

Comment: Worked perfectly :) you learn something every day. Thank you!